# iOS : fix-it replace"<libxm/xmlversion.h>" with ""libxm/xmlversion.h""

Tags: ios, xcode, libxml2

See these pictures and how can I fix this? Thank you!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What were you trying to do? Link to libxml?

Answer (score 0):

In picture 2, it should be "Header Search Paths", but not "User Header Search Paths"